# Eclipse Neon, not compiling

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used earlier versions of eclipse in many of my developments. Now after a break of some time I downloaded eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0). I created a Java Project and Simple HelloWorld Java file. I was surprised that it is not even  compiling.The error I am getting is as below .

> Blocked:The User operation is waiting for "Build workspace" to
>   complete. Below there is a msg : Building workspace(Sleeping)

It seems like a deadlock situation. Did anyone face this issue, any solutions ?

Comment: Try to clean and refresh the project to push the building forward.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. I had tried but still I was faced with the same issue. Then  I remembered the usual solution of restarting the eclipse, after the restart it works and am  able to compile.

Comment: I nevet got this so far. Do you have precise steps to reproduce? Does the Progress view show more detailsabout what's going on?

Comment: I am not sure what are the steps to reproduce this but I got this error after, installing the eclipse Git and JGit plugins, after the installation the eclipse was restarted, then this error scenario, was exhibited.